# How to launch nix-shell with package with a long name

Tags: nix

```
nix-env -iA nixpkgs.python311
```

it works

But when i do a

```
nix-shell -p nixpkgs.python311
```

or a

```
nix-shell -p python3-3.11.1
```

visibly there are problem in the name and arg

> nix-shell -p python3-3.11.1 error: undefined variable 'python3-3'
>
> ```
>    at «string»:1:107:
>
>         1| {...}@args: with import <nixpkgs> args; (pkgs.runCommandCC or pkgs.runCommand) "shell" { buildInputs = [
> ```
>
> (python3-3.11.1) ]; } ""
> |                                                                                                           ^ (use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)

Regards

Comment: It works for me, e.g. `nix-shell -p python311Packages.python`  Maybe you have some mess in your channel/names/NIX_PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass an arbitrary Nix expression to `nix-shell -p`, put it in parenthesis:

```bash
nix-shell -p '((import <nixpkgs> {}).python311)'
```

Anything you could append to `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.` you should be able to append in place of `python311` above. It also can be used for things like:

```bash
nix-shell -p \
  '((import <nixpkgs> {}).python311.withPackages (p: [p.lxml p.pyyaml]))'
```

...to provide Python 3.11 with lxml and PyYAML installed.